# Cómo comparo los elementos de una lista cuyos elementos son tuplas?

Tags: python, lista, comparaciones, tuplas

tengo la siguiente lista,y quiero saber que tuplas son iguales,cómo las comparo?.

```
lista=[(4, 5), (-0, 2), (4, 7), (1, -3), (3, -2), (4, 5),(3, 2), (5, 7), (-5, 7), (2, 2), (-4, 5), (0, -2),(-4, 7), (-1, 3), (-3, 2), (-4, -5), (-3, 2),(5, 7), (5, 7), (2, 2), (9, 9), (-8, -9)].
```

He probado con los indices y buleanos pero me dice que no hay ningun elemento igual,alguna idea??

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. No hay problema en comparar dos tuplas, son consideradas iguales si tienen la misma longitud y sus elementos en el mismo índice son considerados todos también iguales. Sería bueno que agregaras el código para que pudiéramos explicar porqué te falla, demás ¿quieres saber solo las tuplas repetidas o también la posición de las mismas?¿Solo quieres conocerlo o hacer otras cosas como eliminar las duplicadas? Dependiendo de lo que busques hay formas más simples o más eficientes de hacerlo. Un saludo.

Comment: Hola,muchas gracias!!Quiero conocer las tuplas que están repetidas y que me diga el numero de estas en una variable fuera del bucle,es decir,que cuantas tuplas de esa lista son iguales.

Comment: Vale, una última duda XD, si tienes `[(4, 5), (-0, 2), (4, 5), (-0, 2), (7, 3)]` ¿debería retornar como número de repetidas 2 o 4? Por cierto, ¿tienes alguna limitación en cuanto a usar la biblioteca estándar de Python o puedes usar cualquier cosa?

Comment: Vale,me he explicado fatal,la verdad que soy muy neofita de python y lo controlo poco,tengo que hacer dos ejercicios,os planteo el primero de ellos junto con mi "idea de codigo".Me dan la lista anterior y tengo que hacer lo siguiente.
a)Robin Hood is famous for hitting an arrow with another arrow. Did you get it?
b)Calculate how many arrows have fallen in each quadrant.
c)Find the point closest to the center. Calculate its distance to the center.
d)If the target has a radius of 9, calculate the number of arrows that must be picked up in the forest.

Comment: Sobre las 2 primeras planteo algo así;`nRHarrows=0 for RHarrows in(points):
    if x==:
    elif y==:
        nRHarrows+=1
print(nRHarrows)`

Answer (score 1):

Se puede comparar tuplas de la misma manera que números sueltos:

```py
lista = [(4, 5), (-0, 2), (4, 7), (1, -3), (3, -2), (4, 5),(3, 2), (5, 7), (-5, 7), (2, 2), (-4, 5), (0, -2),(-4, 7), (-1, 3), (-3, 2), (-4, -5), (-3, 2),(5, 7), (5, 7), (2, 2), (9, 9), (-8, -9)]

tuplas_repetidas = []
tuplas_repetidas_unicas = []
for i, a in enumerate(lista):
    if a in lista[:i]: # "ya está anteriormente en la lista"
        tuplas_repetidas.append(a)
        if a not in tuplas_repetidas_unicas:
            tuplas_repetidas_unicas.append(a)

print("Hay", len(tuplas_repetidas), "tuplas repetidas.")
print("Son:", tuplas_repetidas)
print("Hay", len(tuplas_repetidas_unicas), "tuplas repetidas una o más veces.")
print("Son:", tuplas_repetidas_unicas)
```

Resultado:

```
Hay 5 tuplas repetidas.
Son: [(4, 5), (-3, 2), (5, 7), (5, 7), (2, 2)]
Hay 4 tuplas repetidas una o más veces.
Son: [(4, 5), (-3, 2), (5, 7), (2, 2)]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias,no quiero que me imprima cuales son las tuplas que se repiten si no cuantas son!.

Comment: ¿La pregunta sigue abierta?